# RegEx to exclude number that begin with some pattern

Tags: r, regex, posix, regex-negation

I have the following list of numbers:

```
5501, 534, 234, 550, 5500
```

I want to select all numbers except "5501" and "5500" and use it with the `stringr` package in `R`.
I tried the following expression without luck:

```
^((?!550)\d)*$
```

Comment: Why use regex if you have a numeric vector?

Comment: Because numbers are in fact "country codes".

Comment: I don't know how to code in R, but this should do the job: `\b(?!550\d\b)(\d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^((?!5501|5500)[0-9]*)$
```

Observe `“Negative Lookahead”` command `?!` in the above regex.
This will exclude `5501` and `5500`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
v1[grep("^.{3}$", v1)]
#[1] 534 234 550
```

Or more specifically

```
v1[grep("^550[01]$", v1, invert=TRUE)]
#[1] 534 234 550
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c(5501, 534, 234, 550, 5500)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only those two exact strings that you want to eliminate (and never 5502 for example) you could use standard R subsetting, there is no need to use regex.

```
x <- c(5501, 534, 234, 550, 5500)
x <- x[x != 5500 & x != 5501]
```

If instead you care about all values that start with 550 but not those which might have 550 somewhere else you could use

```
x<-x[stringi::stri_sub(x, 1,3) != "550"  | x == "550"]
```

Comment: Also consider `x[!x %in% c(5500, 5501)]`

Comment: This would of course potentially give different results than what the poster asked for, since that was for all numbers beginning with 550.  Also they are strings.

Comment: @Elin - no, he writes `I want to select all numbers except "5501" and "5500"`.  He does not write they are string.

Comment: He actually mentions stringr.